# How can I get Display name of azure ad group in .NET 4.6 C#?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using JWT to get the claims from azure ad:

```
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            JwtSecurityToken decodedeIdtoken = handler.ReadToken(base64IDToken) as JwtSecurityToken;
            var claims = decodedeIdtoken.Claims;
```

I am getting this in claims:

***Debug Result***

[image]

I need display name of azure ad group as well, kindly suggest me how can I include group display name here without using graph APIs.

I need display name of azure ad group

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/connect/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims If you followed the guide and had some problems, please be more specific.

Comment: `Microsoft.Graph` package is required to get the display name.But when I tried to add the package Iam getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T40Nk.png).

Comment: Try to upgrade the framework version to 4.6.1 or later.